# How Can I Validate Tailwind CSS Class Names in My Project, Considering Custom Configurations?

Tags: html, css, web, tailwind-css

I am currently working on a project that utilizes Tailwind CSS. Sometimes, I copy Tailwind code from libraries or other sources. Occasionally, I find that some of these class names don't work in my project because my `tailwind.config.js` has been customized or needs to be updated.

I am seeking a way to validate all the Tailwind CSS class names used in my project. Specifically, I'd like to check whether each class name is valid according to my project's Tailwind CSS configuration, including any customizations made in the `tailwind.config.js` file.

Here's an example of a class name that might be used in my project:

```
className="grid min-h-full place-items-center bg-white px-6 py-24 sm:py-32 lg:px-8 happy"
```

In this example, "happy" is not a valid Tailwind CSS class name. I want to identify these types of errors automatically throughout my project.

Here is another example:

```
className="grid min-h-full place-items-center bg-white px-6 py-24 sm:py-32 lg:px-8 flex"
```

In this case, Tailwind CSS IntelliSense displays the error:

```
'flex' applies the same CSS properties as 'grid'.(cssConflict)
```

I believe Tailwind CSS IntelliSense cannot handle invalid class names correctly.

I'm not certain if these methods would accurately handle dynamic class names or classes added at runtime.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to tackle this problem. Thanks in advance for your assistance!